# Find index of first of two characters in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.9

Given the following strings:

```py
foo = "hello + there"
bar = "hello - there"
baz = "one + two - three"
fuz = "one - two + three"
```

Is there a (relatively) direct method to get the index of the first character that is either `+` or `-` ?

```py
foo.index_multiple('+-') # 6
bar.index_multiple('+-') # 6
baz.index_multiple('+-') # 4
fuz.index_multiple('+-') # 4
```

*EDIT: I'm not asking for custom code (e.g. a Python routine) — that is relatively straightforward and I can do this on my own. I'm only interested to know if there's anything built-in for this purpose, that may or may not use regexes.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) in the following way:

```python
import re
string = "test + Line"
match = re.search(r"[+-]", string)
if match:
    print("Character + or - found at ", match.start())
else:
    print("No + or - found")
```